# Select the current word in VSCode when dots or hyphens are present?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How do I select the following words in VSCode:
`button-color` or `button.color` ?

Ctrl-D doesn't work, it just selects the portion before/after the . or -. Ctrl-W also doesn't work even after I changed its defautl setting of closing the editor/open tab.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also change your `Editor: Word Separators` setting.  Remove the `.` and `-` characters and it will work as you want.  Just delete those characters from the list shown in the setting.

[image: word separator setting]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the extension [Select By](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.select-by).

Edit your `keybindings.json`

You can define or redefine the Ctrl+D with

```
  {
    "key": "ctrl+shift+d", // or any other combo
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "command": "selectby.regex",
    "args": {
      "surround": "[-.a-zA-Z0-9]+"
    }
  }
```